# How can I tell Automator to display an image with Preview but actual size?

Tags: macos, automator, preview, automation

I am trying to have Automator do a simple task: display an image, but *actual size*. The problem is that Preview by default wants to 'fit' the image on the screen, but there appears to be no way to tell Automator to tell Preview to do it 'actual size' instead.

Is there a way to do this or do I simply have to find another way and avoid Preview.app?

Comment: What does your **Automator** _workflow_ look like so far?

Comment: What do you consider 'actual size'? Preview prefs can choose between '1pt = 1 px' & 'size on screen = size on printout'.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your actual **Automator** *workflow*, the only thing I can think of off the top of my head is to add a **Run AppleScript** *action*, after the *action* that opens the file in **Preview**, with the following *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "Preview" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Preview"
        if value of ¬
            attribute "AXMenuItemMarkChar" of ¬
            menu item "Actual Size" of ¬
            menu 1 of ¬
            menu bar item "View" of ¬
            menu bar 1 is missing value then
            
            click menu item "Actual Size" of ¬
                menu 1 of ¬
                menu bar item "View" of ¬
                menu bar 1
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```

This is similar to manually pressing **⌘0** while in **Preview**, which activates the **Actual Size** *menu item* on its **View** *menu*, if it is not already showing its actual size.

This also assumes the default preference of **Define 100% scale as: 1 image pixel equals 1 screen pixel** is in play.

---

<sub>**Note:** Using the *example* **AppleScript** *code* may require adjusting settings under: **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy**</sub>

Comment: Both these answers are going to depend on the definition of 'actual size' in Preview prefs. By default, it will open documents at *both* actual size and zoom to fit. I'm still of the opinion they have the pref set to 1pt-1px rather than size on printout.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @user3439894. The easiest thing to do would be to add a “Run AppleScript” action to your Automator workflow.

However, though the solution he provided is perfectly valid, the conditional clause he uses is un-necessary with my alternate solution.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Preview"
    set frontmost to true
    repeat until frontmost
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    click menu item "Actual Size" of menu 1 of menu bar item ¬
        "View" of menu bar 1
end tell
```

If the menu item "Actual Size" is already selected, the code will just finish without throwing an error.

I am also assuming that Preview.app is already running before “Run AppleScript” action in your Automator workflow, otherwise there would be no `application process "Preview”` , therefore it would throw an error.

Comment: Both these answers are going to depend on the definition of 'actual size' in Preview prefs. By default, it will open documents at *both* actual size and zoom to fit. I'm still of the opinion they have the pref set to 1pt-1px rather than size on printout.

Comment: RE: "If the menu item "Actual Size" is already selected, the code will just finish without throwing an error."  -- That is not necessarily true, as it will _ring the bell_ so to speak, and this can be annoying. As _coded_ in my answer it avoids needlessly clicking the _menu item_ and in turn one does not hear any sound if it's already actual size.

Comment: Hmmm.. @user3439894, I’m not getting any sort of sound or screen flash If the menu item "Actual Size" is already selected. But wrapping the code inside a `try` block (without an `on error` clause) should stop the “bell from ringing”

Comment: **macOS** by default has **Play user interface sound effects** check under **System Preferences** > **Sound** > **Sound Effects** and if other defaults are in play and one has the volume turned up then one should here a sound when clicking a greyed out menu item which it is if it's already showing at the actual size. This is why I made it conditional.